# ls files with associated types

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, command-prompt

I list contents of pwd

`ls`

But get a bunch of names. And I don't know which are directories and which aren't.

How do I list out the contents of a folder with each item's associated filetype?

Comment: `ls -al` perhaps? *man ls* is a great reference for all things `ls`...

Comment: `ls -l|awk '/^d/{print}'`  will list all the directories (all the lines starting with "d" from `ls -l`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$ ls -F
```

or

```
$ ls --file-type
```

Comment: Long options, like `--file-type`, are not POSIX standard.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `ls` command with the option `-l`, the first string of letters gives the info about each file, and the first letter in this string gives the file's type. (`d` = directory, `-` = standard file, `l` = link, etc.)

Comment: doesn't say the filetype though

Comment: What exactly do you mean by file **type**? Maybe a classification like the one the `file` command provides? (see `man file`).